# How can I detect whether the button is at the bottom of screen and not on top of screen using Appium?

Tags: android, ios, appium

I tried using `getSize()` or `getLocation()` but then they doesn't tell whether it's at bottom or top of screen.

How can I solve this?

Comment: Welcome, to improve your experience on Stack Overflow please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) an [On Topic question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and the [Question Check list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) and [the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and if not already done, [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Answer (score 0):

Appium detects the button itself. All you need to do is give the correct commmand. Using *UIAutomator* you can pass the button *id*, *ClassName*, *Xpath* etc for the Appium to detect the button.